# Name a abelian subgroup which is not normal

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was looking through a study guide for an abstract algebra course and I'm trying to work through a lot of material independently.

I was hoping if someone could give me the simplest example to my problem and maybe a short explanation.

Q: Name an abelian group which is not normal.

Comment: It never makes sense to say that a group is normal or not normal.  Normality is a relationship that a subgroup has to a larger group.  A group $H$ that is a subgroup of $G$ might be normal in $G$ or not; when $H$ is considered as a subgroup of some other group $G'$ the answer might be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G=S_3$ and let $H=\{e,(12)\}$. Then $H$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$, but it is not a normal subgroup of $G$ because, for example, letting $g=(13)$
$$gHg^{-1}=\{e,(23)\}\neq H.$$

Comment: Great! thanks for your answer I really appreciate it!